# Implementar diferentes tipos de descuentos a Productos - PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, poo

como estan?
Estoy haciendo un shop en PHP con CodeIgniter y tengo un problema con lo siguiente:
Quiero que mis productos puedan recibir 2 tipos de descuentos: un descuento % del precio total o un importe fijo. Para lograr esto, pensé en algo asi:

```
abstract class Descuento
{
    /**
     * @var float valor de descuento
     */
    protected $descuento;

    public function __construct($descuento)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->descuento = $descuento;
    }

    public function getDescuento()
    {
        return $this->descuento;
    }

    abstract function aplicarA(Item $item);
}

class DescuentoImporte extends Descuento
{
    function aplicarA(Item $item)
    {
        return $item->getPrecioLista() - $this->descuento;
    }
}

class DescuentoPorcentaje extends Descuento_Model
{
    function aplicarA(Item $item)
    {
        $precioLista = $item->getPrecioLista();
        return $this->descuento > 0? $precioLista - $precioLista * $this->descuento : $precioLista;
    }
}
```

Luego, mi clase Producto tendría un atributo del tipo Descuento donde almacenaria alguno de estos descuentos si los tuvieran o se los podría inyectar mediante el setter.
El problema que encuentro con esta idea es como persistir los descuentos de manera que al traerlos de la base de datos sepan si el descuento es % o fijo.

Probablemente me la esté complicando, se les ocurre alguna manera más sencilla o práctica de implementar este requerimiento?
Desde ya, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola fethe, primero que nada, si estás utilizando CodeIgniter tu implementación está mal, sólo debes de tener una clase con el mismo nombre del archivo (ControladorProducto.php o cualquier nombre que gustes) Te recomiendo que consultes un ejemplo sencillo utilizando CI

Comment: cada clase sería un archivo diferente, lo pongo todo junto acá para facilitar la lectura. Tampoco serían controladores en este caso, o al menos no lo pensé así. He hecho cosas sencillas con Codeigniter, el problema es que lo que necesito hacer ahora no es tan sencillo (al menos para mi) y no se como encararlo.

Comment: Algo que podría resolver tu problema es enviar en un array tanto el valor del descuento como el tipo, ['tipo'=>'importe','valor'=>'20'] y en la función que lo recibe validarlo if(tipo=='importe'){ precio-=valor}... else precio=precio * (1/(100-valor))

Comment: gracias! eso me puede servir